grep command regexp behaviour, is there a workaround?
I wanted to extract from a text all capitalized words that do not start a sentence or follow a period.
I managed to do it with a combination of sed and grep but got stuck for a while with grep's behaviour. I thought that the regexp '[^(.)]\s[A-Z][a-z]*' would give me "all words starting with a capital preceded by anything_but_a_period then a space"
Well that doesn't work!
echo "Hello. My name is James Bond." | grep -o "[^(\.)]\s[A-Z][a-z]*"

gives
s James

while I expected:
s James
s Bond

I understand that the last 's' of 'James' being already grepped by grep, 's Bond' is not considered to be in the form of [a-z]\s[A-Z]* but what bothers me is that it is definitely in the form of 'anything_but_a_period then a space'.
But then how could it be defined? It is not either in the form of ^\s[A-Z] as ^ only refers to the beginning of the line.
Would there be:

a way to describe an "already grepped expression" (that would work like ^ for instance in my example)
a way to tweak my grep command so that both James and Bond are given as results

Again, I'm not asking for a way to solve the original problem (extract from a text all capitalized words that do not start a sentence or follow a period) as I've done it with sed.
I am rather curious of solving the problem with just grep in an elegant way.

Also: "anything_but_a_period" is just [^.]. [^(\.)] is anything but parentheses, backslash or period.

@muru yes sorry, the regexp was way more complex than that, I tried to simplify as much as I could but still left a few chars behind

If your grep supports it, you could use its perl regexp mode (generally with -P) and use a negative look-behind operator:
$ echo "Hello. My name is James Bond, not Jean-Pierre nor Dr. Who! Nor Πυθαγόρας ὁ Σάμιος, nor C3PO" |
    grep -Po '(?<!^|[.!?()\s])\s*\K\p{Lu}\pL*'
James
Bond
Jean
Pierre
Dr
Πυθαγόρας
Σάμιος
C
PO

That matches on \s*\K\p{Lu}\pL*, that is any amount (*) of white\space followed by an uppercase Letter followed by any number of Letters (though we \Keep only the letters) provided what's behind (<) is not (!) the start of the line (^) nor any of the .!?() characters nor a white\space, using the (?<!...) negative look-behind operator.

That is indeed a very elegant and working solution. But could you break it down a bit, I struggle to wrap my head around it.

@Pikko, see edit. See man pcrepattern (or pcre2pattern these days) or perldoc perlre for details.

Great! man pcrepattern is a goldmine indeed. I was kinda confused with \p{Lu} but it makes sense now. The absolute revelation for me is \K though, as I used to filter the extra characters with awk.
